# Share info on friends timeline (Facebook sdk, iPhone)

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to give the users of my iphone app the option to recommend things to their friends on facebook. Like a button in the app that says: "Share this with your friend". Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can share any message from iPhone application. You can use facebook graph API for sharing message to facebook.